# Top section of page is not visible while hints are off

Tags: magento-1.7

I am very new to magento and have developed theme. 
When I try to use my theme I am unable to see header.phtml, head.phtml etc in my page. 
In page source I am seeing all stuff but thats not visible on page.

When hints are on I am seeing all stuff correctly with hints.

Please help me out.

This is my URL..

```
http://216.12.194.46/~kartscom/kartsftp/magento/index.php/computer/sony.html
```

Regards, 
Suraj.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your header-container (and possibly header) does not close itself correctly.

I suggest checking the file /app/design/frontend/my_company/default/template/page/html/header.phtml to make sure each div closes itself.

By enabling hints, the hint boxes (which are made by div tags) end up closing the containers, which is why it shows correctly with it on, except for the fact that the box labeled as "frontend/my_company/default/template/page/html/header.phtml" (Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header) in your hints extends all the way down the page.

The "header-container" div needs to close before the "main-container col2-right-layout" div. To help deduce any other errors, I suggest starting off by turning hints off and running your page through the [W3C Html Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), and trying to correct as many issues as possible.

The validator tool will definitely help in tracking down any tags that aren't being closed, plus I always strive to have pages that pass with 0 errors / 0 warnings.

Comment: Thanks Jason it is helpful for Resolving my problem.